# photon OnRoomListUpdate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am making room List system in photon, but

```
public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
```

This command doesn't work well.  How can I fix it?

<PhotonManager.cs>

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class PhotonManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    private readonly string gameVersion = "v1.0";
    private string userID = "igw";

    public TMP_InputField userIDText;
    public TMP_InputField roomNameText;

    private Dictionary<string,GameObject> roomDict=new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

    public GameObject roomPrefab;
    public Transform scrollContent;

    public Text PhotonMessage;

    public LobbyManager LobbyManager;

    private void Awake()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        PhotonNetwork.SendRate = 60;
        PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate = 30;
        PhotonNetwork.GameVersion=gameVersion;
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        userID = PlayerPrefs.GetString("USER_ID", $"USER_{Random.Range(0, 100):00}");
        userIDText.text = userID;
        PhotonNetwork.NickName=userID;
    }
    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonMessage.color = Color.white;
        PhotonMessage.text = "Connected Server";
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        PhotonMessage.color = Color.white;
        PhotonMessage.text = "Joined Lobby";
    }

    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        PhotonMessage.color = Color.red;
        PhotonMessage.text = "Failed to Join";

        RoomOptions ro=new RoomOptions();
        ro.IsOpen = true;
        ro.IsVisible = true;
        ro.MaxPlayers = LobbyManager.MaxPlayerNum;

        roomNameText.text = $"Room_{Random.Range(1, 100):000}";

        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("room_1", ro);
    }

    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        PhotonMessage.color = Color.white;
        PhotonMessage.text = "Created Room";
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonMessage.color = Color.white;
        PhotonMessage.text = "Joined Room";
        //PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
    }
    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        Debug.Log("Update!");
        GameObject tempRoom = null;
        foreach (var room in roomList)
        {
            if (room.RemovedFromList == true)
            {
                roomDict.TryGetValue(room.Name, out tempRoom);
                Destroy(tempRoom);
                roomDict.Remove(room.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                if (roomDict.ContainsKey(room.Name) == false)
                {
                    GameObject _room = Instantiate(roomPrefab, scrollContent);
                    _room.GetComponent<RoomData>().RoomInfo = room;
                    roomDict.Add(room.Name, _room);
                }
                else
                {
                    roomDict.TryGetValue(room.Name, out tempRoom);
                    tempRoom.GetComponent<RoomData>().RoomInfo = room;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region UI_BUTTON_CALLBACK

    public void OnRandomBtn()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIDText.text))
        {
            userID = $"USER_{Random.Range(0, 100):00}";
            userIDText.text=userID;
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("USER_ID",userIDText.text);
        PhotonNetwork.NickName=userIDText.text;
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    public void onMakeRoomClick()
    {
        RoomOptions ro=new RoomOptions();
        ro.IsOpen = true;
        ro.IsVisible = true;
        ro.MaxPlayers = LobbyManager.MaxPlayerNum;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(roomNameText.text))
        {
            roomNameText.text = $"ROOM_{Random.Range(1, 100):000}";
        }
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomNameText.text,ro);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

<RoomData.cs>

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using TMPro;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Photon.Pun.Demo.Cockpit;

public class RoomData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text RoomInfoText;
    private RoomInfo _roomInfo;

    public TMP_InputField NicknameText;
    public LobbyManager LobbyManager;

    public RoomInfo RoomInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _roomInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            _roomInfo = value;
            RoomInfoText.text = $"{_roomInfo.Name} ({_roomInfo.PlayerCount}/{_roomInfo.MaxPlayers})";
            GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=>OnEnterRoom(_roomInfo.Name));
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        LobbyManager = GameObject.Find("LobbyManager").GetComponent<LobbyManager>();
        NicknameText = GameObject.Find("NicmnameINP").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
    }

    public void OnEnterRoom(string roomName)
    {
        RoomOptions ro=new RoomOptions();
        ro.IsOpen = true;
        ro.IsVisible = true;
        ro.MaxPlayers = LobbyManager.MaxPlayerNum;
        PhotonNetwork.NickName=NicknameText.text;
        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(roomName, ro,TypedLobby.Default);
    }
}
```

<LobbyManager.cs>

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LobbyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PopUp;
    public int MaxPlayerNum;
    public Text PlayerNumText;

    private void Start()
    {
        PopUp.SetActive(false);
        MaxPlayerNum = 2;
        PlayerNumText.text = "2";
    }

    public void PlayerUpbtn()
    {
        if (MaxPlayerNum < 6)
        {
            MaxPlayerNum++;
            PlayerNumText.text = MaxPlayerNum.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PlayerDownbtn()
    {
        if(MaxPlayerNum > 2)
        {
            MaxPlayerNum--;
            PlayerNumText.text = MaxPlayerNum.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PopUpbtn()
    {
        PopUp.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void ClosePopUpbtn()
    {
        PopUp.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

```
public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
```

this command worked Only when I first enter the lobby.

when I create a room in development Build, this command not worked

Comment: +        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom(); is not working too. I think photon doesn't seem to recognize the room